# How do I turn on advanced telemetry in an AIR app?

Tags: flash, air

How do I turn on advanced telemetry in an AIR app? In Flex apps in the browser you would drag and drop the SWF onto a program called SWF Scout Enabler but with AIR apps you don't have a SWF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apache Flex 4.10 or greater add to your compiler options:

```
-advanced-telemetry=true
```

[Source](http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Usage-of-Adobe-Scout-tp2915p2955.html)